# How to automatically update a countdown date/time counter through macros on Microsoft Word?

Tags: vba, ms-word

## **How to automatically update a countdown date/time counter through macros on Microsoft Word?**

**Background:**
I have a Knowledge Article (How To guide) for my staff to use. I am wanting the document to be revised every 6 months.

What I am attempting to achieve with this macro is to have an editor of the document (eg. myself). Run the Macro and put in a future date. Then have that date on the document automatically update each time the document is opened (so you can see the current days remaining).
Then at the 6 months mark have the ability to change the date/run the macro again.*

This is my current code:
(Currently works, but of course no automatic update feature)

```
Sub CountdownFromTodayToRevisionDate()
   Dim dtRevisionDate As Date
   Dim lDaysLeft As Long

' Input the revision date to calculate the date difference.
dtRevisionDate = InputBox("ENTER NEXT REVISION DATE BELOW" & vbCrLf & "Note:  6 months from last revision", "Set Revision Date")

' Output the date difference from today to the revision date in word document.
Selection.Text = "" & lDaysLeft & " days until next revision." & vbCrLf & "Last Revision: " & dtRevisionDate & vbCrLf

End Sub
```

Comment: Look into the `Document_Open` event - it fires "automatically" every time the document is opened.